# OutVariable contains incorrect data when using Select-Object with the First parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

```
 $somevar = Get-Process -OutVariable var | Select-Object -First 5
```

Why does $var = $somevar (both have only first 5 objects) in this case? Why doesn't `-OutVariable` save proper output to $var? I'm confused.

```
C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.206
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.206
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

C:\>  [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      14393  0
```

Comment: Weird, seems to be a version 5.x thing

Comment: Just tested on 2012r2, same thing. do you have 5.x? can you test this?

Comment: Change must have been introduced in 3 or 4 then, `powershell -v 2 -noexit -command "Get-Process -ov var |Select -First 5;$var"` produces the expected result

Comment: the same on PS3

Comment: `Select-Object -First 5 -Wait`

Comment: can you please elaborate, why does it happen like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In Powershell 3.0 optimization was included with Select-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object). You are seeing a feature

> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, Select-Object includes an optimization feature that prevents commands from creating and processing objects that are not used. **When you include a Select-Object command with the First or Index parameter in a command pipeline, Windows PowerShell stops the command that generates the objects as soon as the selected number of objects is generated**, even when the command that generates the objects appears before the Select-Object command in the pipeline. To turn off this optimizing behavior, use the Wait parameter.

Using `-Wait` cancels this behavior. The command takes longer when you do so but it allows your expected behavior to occur.

If it matters to anyone there is a footnote caveat on the optimizations features prerequisite:

> The optimization feature of Select-Object is available only for commands that write objects to the pipeline as they are processed. It has no effect on commands that buffer processed objects and write them as a collection